# Is conspiracy a crime under Jewish law? If so, under what circumstances?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory

In US law, criminal conspiracy is a crime. (See below for definition.)

Is there a similar concept in halacha and, if so, under what circumstances and how does it work (e.g., when is it a crime and what is the punishment)?  In short, is conspiracy to sin a crime even if the planned sin/crime never came to pass?

Under US law, the web tells us:
A criminal conspiracy is an agreement to commit an unlawful act.  The agreement itself is the crime, but at least one co-conspirator must take an “overt act” (not necessarily criminal in itself) in furtherance of the conspiracy.
For example see http://www.mololamken.com/news-knowledge-14.html or https://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-charges/conspiracy.html

Comment: לא תהיה אחרי רבים לרעות

Comment: @Heshy What is your point?

Comment: Are you asking if conspiracy to sin a crime in general or if any particular sins are conspiracy like?

Comment: @DoubleAA. Yes, is conspiracy to sin a crime?

Comment: Would you count a massis, the one who says "let us serve other gods"? He gets stoned.

Comment: @Mordechai  There the words themselves are Biblically prohibited. The sin is encouraging others to avoda zora.  So that is different from saying to another person, "Let's rob ploni".

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with you, but I'd have to look into it.

Comment: We hold that "מחשבה רעה אין הקב”ה מצרפה למעשה" - having bad thoughts is not a crime, so even if witnessed, the witnesses have nothing to testify about.

Answer (score 4):

The Rambam discusses cases which I believe are what you call conspiracy ([MT Rotzeach uShmirat Nefesh 2:2](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam.asp?tdate=11/10/2019))

> **But a person who hires a murderer to kill a colleague, one who sends
>   his servants and they kill him**, one who binds a colleague and leaves
>   him before a lion or the like and the beast kills him, and a person
>   who commits suicide are all considered to be shedders of blood; **the
>   sin of bloodshed is upon their hands, and they are liable for death at
>   the hands of God. They are not, however, liable for execution by the
>   court.**

Then in 2:4

> **When a Jewish king desires to slay any of these murderer**s and the like
>   - who are not liable for execution by the court - by virtue of his regal authority, in order to perfect society, **he has the license**.
>
> Similarly, if the court desires to execute them as a result of a
>   immediate fiat, because this was required at the time, they have the
>   license to do as they see fit.

and 2:5

> **If the king did not execute them, nor did the court deem the time as
>   such to require strengthening the strictures against murder, it should
>   nevertheless have the murderer beaten with severe blows** - so that he
>   is on the verge of death - **and imprisoned, deprived and afflicted with
>   all types of discomfort in order to strike fear and awe into the
>   hearts of other wicked men**, so that this death should not be a
>   stumbling block and a snag for them, causing them to say: "Let me
>   arrange to have my enemies killed the way so-and-so did, and I will
>   not suffer the consequences."

Comment: In your first example, what if the murder never took place? Is planning the murder a crime in itself?

Comment: The language of the Rambam is that there needs to be a criminal action. I do not believe one is liable to plan to murder without action. In general, Judaism judges actions not thoughts or plans